# Sum up any pair of pizza that are in the same restaurant in SQL

Tags: sql

**Conditions:**

1. Budget of $40
2. Buy 2 distinct pizza from the same restaurant

**Expected Results:** List of restaurants that fulfill the above conditions

**Database schema:** Customers(cname, area), Restaurants(rname, area), Pizzas(pizza), Sells(rname,pizza,price), Likes(cname, pizza)

**Sells table**

```
| rname  | Pizzas    | Price |
------------------------------
| rname1 | Hawaiian  | $10   |
| rname2 | Hawaiian  | $20   |
| rname2 | Pizza3    | $20   |
| rname3 | Pizza4    | $20   |
```

So in this case, rname2 will be the answer since $20+$20 = $40. And they are from the same restaurant and the two pizzas are distinct.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT s.rname
FROM Sells s
WHERE s.price < 40   -- Max $40 only. How to total up price of 2 pizzas here?
GROUP BY s.rname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.pizza)>=2
```

Update:
My issue is that i want to check if there are 2 distinct pizza that does not exceed the budget of $40 in each of the restaurants. 
Not the sum of the whole column.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: adding the price of two distinct pizzas in a restaurant. the condition is that the total must be the most $40.

Comment: If you're trying to get the sum of any pair of pizzas, you're going to need to do a self-join.

Comment: @user8779054 you need to store prices and numbers, not string

Comment: @admcfajn it's not a duplicate since the linked question is about summing all of the rows with a common column, whereas this question is about pair-wise summing.

Comment: Hawaiian Pizza isn't pizza. Pineapple on Pizza is misery pie. This question is too localized. VTC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a self join:

```
select s1.rname, s1.pizza, s2.pizza
from sales s1 join
     sales s2
     on s1.rname = s2.rname and s1.pizza < s2.pizza
where s1.price + s2.price = 40;
```

"Budget" suggests `<=` for the comparison.  But the question itself has `$20+$20 = $40`, suggesting that you really intend equality.

Comment: I'd probably do `s1.pizza < s2.pizza` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I think `s1.price + s2.price <= 40` as the budget is 40 and I assume that means less is ok as well as long as is not exceeded.

Comment: @Igor yes. It wasn't totally clear from the OP's wording. It says "budget" of $40, but then the text says "adds up to $40".

Comment: @lurker - true. Their SQL attempt also has less than 40.

Comment: Yes. Thanks all. It is s1.price + s2.price <= 40.

Comment: @Igor yes, good point, and it being oddly strictly less than 40.